# Expected value of dependent variables

Tags: probability, expectation

Suppose we have 
$$
x\sim Normal(x|0,\Sigma)
$$
where $x\in R^N$ and
$$
\Sigma\sim Wishart(\Sigma|w,\Psi)
$$
where $w\in R$ and $\Psi$ is a $N\times N$ semi-positive matrix.

How can we compute $E[x^T\Sigma x]$?

the solution may be started as below

$$
x^T\Sigma x=\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1,...,x_N
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_{11}^2       & \sigma_{12}^2   & \dots & \sigma_{1N}^2  \\
    \sigma_{21} ^2       & \sigma_{22}^2   & \dots & \sigma_{2N} ^2 \\
    &&...&& \\
    \sigma_{N1}    ^2    & \sigma_{N2}^2   & \dots & \sigma_{NN}^2 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1\\\vdots\\x_N
\end{bmatrix}=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N x_i\sigma_{ij}^2 x_j
$$
therefore
$$
E[x^T\Sigma x]=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N E[x_i\sigma_{ij}^2 x_j]
$$
and what should I do in the following?

Comment: 14 views! one negative point!! (Why?!?!) and no answer! :|

Comment: By the way, I suspect its inverse Wishart, not Wishart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
E[x_i \sigma^2_{ij} x_j] = E[E[x_i \sigma^2_{ij} x_j \mid \sigma^2_{ij}]] = E[(\sigma_{ij}^2)^2] = \text{Var}(\sigma_{ij}^2) + E[\sigma_{ij}^2]^2
$$